# How to modify bootstrap code for signup to check for email duplicates?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using the default code for a regular contact_me form. It bring success or failure based on the server response (from my understanding). This code calls msend_form.php which takes care of the communication with the database. It returns true at all times. I am able there to check for pre existing email in the db. The question is how can I pass that to ajax code so that it would display an error not only for server response, but for existing email as well. Here is the code in msend_form.js:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "././mail/msend_form.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            fname: firstName,
            gender: gender,
            email: email
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function() {
            // Success message
            $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
            $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                .append("</button>");
            $('#success > .alert-success')
                .append("<strong>Thank you for registering! </strong>");
            $('#success > .alert-success')
                .append('</div>');

            //clear all fields
            $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
        },
        error: function() {
            // Fail message
            $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
            $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                .append("</button>");
            $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Sorry " + firstname + ", it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later!");
            $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
            //clear all fields
            $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
        },
    })
```

The code in msend_form.php:

```
<?php
// insert in sql database
include '../db_connect.php';


// check if fields passed are empty
if(empty($_POST['fname'])       ||
   empty($_POST['email'])       ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
    echo "No arguments Provided!";
    return false;
   }

$fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
$email_address = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$gender = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gender']);
$ip = 1;

$sqlemail=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `sdusers` WHERE email="'.$email_address.'"');
$res2=mysql_num_rows($sqlemail);

if($res2>=1)
{
    echo 'Email already in use';

}
else
{
    //insert query goes here
    $sql='INSERT INTO `sdusers` (fname, gender, email, ip, time_registered) VALUES ("'.$fname.'","'.$gender.'","'.$email_address.'","'.$ip.'",CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)';
    $res3=mysql_query($sql);

}

mysql_close($link);

return true;            
?>
```

The code in index.php:

```
        <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
            <div class="row control-group">
                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                    <label>First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" id="fname" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your first name.">
                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row control-group">
                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                    <label>Email Address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row control-group">
                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                    <label>Gender</label>
                    <select id="gender" name="gender" class="form-control">
                        <option value="female">Female</option>
                        <option value="male">Male</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <br>
            <div id="success"></div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Thanks

UPDATE:

```
$.ajax({
                url: "././mail/msend_form.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    fname: firstName,
                    gender: gender,
                    email: email
                },
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                success: function(response) {
                    if(response.status == 1){
                        // ok
                        // Success message
                        $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                        $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                            .append("</button>");
                        $('#success > .alert-success')
                            .append("<strong>Thank you for registering! We will contact you once this app is deployed soon. </strong>");
                        $('#success > .alert-success')
                            .append('</div>');
                    }else{
                        // fail
                        // Danger message
                        $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                        $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                            .append("</button>");
                        $('#success > .alert-danger')
                            .append("<strong>Email address already in use. </strong>");
                        $('#success > .alert-danger')
                            .append('</div>');
                    }


                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
                error: function() {
                    // Fail message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Sorry " + firstname + ", it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later!");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
            })
```

Comment: a good idea is to set the status code of the response to have an error code, if you can show the php code, could have a look how to add this in

Comment: just added the php code as requested

Answer (score 3):

success callback fired when server respond with 200 status

if you want to say error in `error` function you need send header 500 (server error) from backend for example

Also you can send bool(int) flag in success response:

```
{status: 1, message: "email does not exists"}

or

{status: 0, message: "email alredy taken"}
```

JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "././mail/msend_form.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        fname: firstName,
        gender: gender,
        email: email
    },
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: function(response) {
        if(response.status == 1){
            // ok
        }else{
            // fail
        }
    }
});
```

php

```
// check for existing email

$email_exists = false; // or true

$json = ['status' => 0, 'message' => 'Email exists']; // default

if(!$email_exists){
    $json['status'] = 1;
    $json['message'] = 'OK';
}

// delete all outputs before header (echo, print_r...)

header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo json_encode($json);
die;
```

Comment: I just added the php code to the question. How could that flag be sent from php to ajax?

Comment: you can echo "0" or echo "1" for very simple. But i recommend you to use json. it will be `echo json_encode(['status' => 1, 'message' => 'msg....']);`.
If you will use json, dont forget to set Content-Type header to application/json, and in $.ajax set `dataType: "json"`

Comment: Please see updated code following your code. For some reason, it displays fine when status is 1, but otherwise it show an alert-danger with nothing written in it

Comment: You have response.message field for this

Comment: sorry this is the first time I am learning ajax, I really have no idea about how it can be done otherwise. I modified the existing code in a way so that it should work the same for the success and error messages. It is possible to get it done that way?